# How to duplicate INSERTS into a separate table?

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers, duplicate-data

An iPhone application I have installed uses an SQLite database to log entries with basic INSERTS and DELETES being performed on it.

However I wish to keep a permanent log of the INSERTS made to this table, so when an INSERT occurs, I want it to be written to another table also so as to create a log.

I don't have access to the application source code in order to modify the SQL statements made, but I do have access to the SQLite database.

Can I do this with triggers? If so can somebody provide a short example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used SQLite, but here is the first link from google: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

you could write something like this probably:

```
CREATE TRIGGER duplicate_insert INSERT ON myTable
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO myDuplicateTable
        VALUES(new.Id, new.Name, new.LastModified)
    END;
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, your example code works perfectly.

May I ask why the new.* prefix is required in the statement?

Comment: the `new.*` refers to the new record being inserted into the table. If you write an update or delete trigger, the `old.*` is also available, and obviously points to the old record.

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the SQLite reference that you reach with Google and the search terms 'sqlite trigger' (namely [SQLite Query Language: CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)) are you having difficulty understanding?

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_maintable AFTER INSERT ON MainTable
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO LoggingTable VALUES(NEW.Column1, ...); END;
```

Untested code...if the syntax diagram is to be believed, both semi-colons are needed; or, at least, the one before the END is needed.