# SQLite: Using a table as a base for other tables

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I am building a database for a small organisation with around 100 to 200 members. Those members have to pay a small fee to be a member.

I have created a table where all the details of the members are listed:

```
------------------------------------------
| First name | Last Name | Address  | ...
------------------------------------------
| John       | Smith     | Street 1 | ...
| Jane       | Smith     | Street 2 | ...
| ...        | ...       | ...      | ...
```

Now I want to create a table where the names of the members are displayed and if they have paid there fee:

```
----------------------
| Name       | Paid? |
----------------------
| John Smith | yes   |
| Jane Smith | no    |
| ...        | ...   |
```

Here comes the problem: if a new member is added to the first table, this should be reflected in the second. If a member is no longer a member, the same has to happen.
I searched the internet for solutions, but could only find ones where the table was dropped and recreated, but this isn't really viable as the data in the second table is really important. We don't want a member that already has paid his fee to have to pay it again.

I want to know:

1. Is this even possible with the use of SQLite?
2. If there is a solution, is it guaranteed to keep the data in the second table in the right place?

P.S.: After writing this question, I thought of creating a temporary table, copying the data of the second table, repopulating the original and then copying back the data out of the temporary table. This seems very devious and very difficult to do with a tool like SQLiteStudio. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think more in terms of operations on the data, than how you store it.

This is a typical normalization problem. There are as many tuples in members as in paid; both have the same primary key. So you should combine both tables.

Add the field paid to your table members, and make it by default "no".

For instance:

```
create table members(
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  paid   bool default false,
   -- any other fields
  primary key (firstname, lastname)
```

);

and if you insert:

```
insert into members(firstname, lastname) values ('john', 'smith');
```

you will get:

```
| firstname | lastname | paid  |
|-----------+----------+-------|
| john      | smith    | false |
```

Alternatively you can keep a paid table, declare a foreign key constraint from that table to members (so any tuple in paid has a tuple in members) and then assume that if a member is not in paid, then it has not paid. 
Otherwise use the value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers that are supported by SQLite.

The link bellow show how create a trigger on insert data:

- [How to duplicate INSERTS into a separate table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489234/how-to-duplicate-inserts-into-a-separate-table)

And the next link show how create a trigger on delete data:

- [SQLite Trigger Expression For Deleting Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197019/sqlite-trigger-expression-for-deleting-rows)